# How can I configure Amazon CDK to trigger a Lambda function after deployment?

Tags: lambda, aws-cdk

I have deployed a Lambda function using Amazon CDK. I would like to invoke this Lambda function automatically every time it is deployed. Is it possible to achieve this using the Amazon CDK construct?

Comment: Does the lambda change each time or is it functionally the same and you just want it to be re-ran?

Comment: @lpbearden the lambda function does not change each time. Let's say I deployed the function in a stack called "lambda-stack." I would like to trigger the function every time I run cdk deploy lambda-stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a CustomResource similar to below:

```js
const lambdaTrigger = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'MyFunctionTrigger', {
  policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
    new iam.PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['lambda:InvokeFunction'],
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: [myFunction.functionArn],
    }),
  ]),
  timeout: Duration.minutes(2),
  onCreate: {
    service: 'Lambda',
    action: 'invoke',
    parameters: {
      FunctionName: myFunction.functionName,
      InvocationType: 'Event',
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
  },
  onUpdate: {
    service: 'Lambda',
    action: 'invoke',
    parameters: {
      FunctionName: myFunction.functionName,
      InvocationType: 'Event'
    },
    physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString())
  }
});
```

By setting the `physicalResourceId` to the current time on deploy it should trigger it to execute each deployment.

Comment: You don't have to define `onCreate` - the default behavior is to use `onUpdate` for creation. Also, using `fromSdkCalls()` is arguably cleaner than `fromStatements()`. But anyway, I this workaround is not needed anymore now that CDK triggers are a thing.

Comment: @gshpychka I didn't test it specifically, but as far as I'm aware Triggers for lambdas only work if the lamdba's handler has changed. This [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html#re-execution-of-triggers) looks like they may add an option to execute on every deploy in the future. It wouldn't work in the case of the lambda being unchanged.

Comment: Yup, looks that way. Would need to use a similar hack to what's in this answer. But allows us to avoid a lot of verbosity in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way to do this is using [CDK triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html), but as @ipbearden correctly points out in the comments, the functionality to run a trigger on every deploy has not been added yet. You can use a hack to always recreate the Trigger on every deploy:

```js
import * as triggers from 'aws-cdk-lib/triggers';

const func: lambda.Function;

new triggers.Trigger(this, 'MyTrigger-' + Date.now().toString(), {
  handler: func,
});
```

You can even have it execute after (or before) the deployment of a specific construct.

Comment: Based on this [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html#re-execution-of-triggers), I don't believe this works for the given use case. This will only work if the actual handler is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with both the `triggers.Trigger` solution and the `customResources.AwsCustomResource` solution, but ultimately, while both of these solutions work, they have some minor drawbacks.

The former's drawback is that it doesn't take in an existing `lambda.Function`, and the latter's drawback is that the Lambda function itself needs to be written as a custom resource event handler, and what's more, we end up with a nonempty `cdk` diff every time.

I've come up with this solution, which uses an `EventBridge` rule to trigger `myFunction` once the `CloudFormation` stack deployment is complete, and with which I am quite happy:

```ts
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib/core";
import * as events from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-events";
import * as eventsTargets from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-events-targets";

new events.Rule(this, "DeploymentHook", {
  eventPattern: {
    detailType: ["CloudFormation Stack Status Change"],
    source: ["aws.cloudformation"],
    detail: {
      "stack-id": [cdk.Stack.of(this).stackId],
      "status-details": {
        status: ["CREATE_COMPLETE", "UPDATE_COMPLETE"],
      },
    },
  },
  targets: [new eventsTargets.LambdaFunction(myFunction)],
});
```